# How to check whether session has already open transaction or not in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, session, transactions, struts

My requirement is i want to perform a database operation.
So, i am doing...

```
Public boolean myFunction(){
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    if(session!=null){
        if (tx != null) {
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            //Perform database operation...
            tx.rollback();
            if (session.isOpen()) {
            session.close();
            }
            tx = null;
            session = null;
        }
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
```

This works good when my session does not contain any previously uncommited/unrolledback tranasction.

Now, Problem Sceanario is here...

Sceanario:

there is one service... which called myFunction() and that service has already one active transaction in session.

Problem:
When myfunction() executes tx.rollback()... it also rolled back parent's transaction.

```
1.) Why this happen???
2.) Is there nay way to determine... weather hibernate session contains any previous open/uncommited/active/unrolledback/continue transaction?
```

I have tried...

```
Public boolean myFunction(){
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    if(session!=null){
        if (tx != null) {
            boolean isAlreadyTransactionStarted = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive();
            if(isAlreadyTransactionStarted){
                Transaction tx = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction();
            }else{
                Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            }
            //Perform database operation...
            if(isAlreadyTransactionStarted){
                tx.rollback();
                if (session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
                }
                tx = null;
                session = null;
            }else{
                //Nothing to do...
            }
        }
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
```

but in the case

```
1.) When parent call contains any active transactions then isAlreadyTransactionStarted becomes true.

2.) But in the case call which does not contains any transaction, also isAlreadyTransactionStarted becomes true.
```

My question is still same:

*Is there nay way to determine... weather hibernate session contains any previous open/uncommited/active/unrolledback/continue transaction?*

Answer (score 1):

Can you use Session.isDirty() ?

Comment: it gives me an exception: org.hibernate.HibernateException: isDirty is not valid without active transaction

Comment: Well... there you go :) Now you know there's no transaction.... But seriously, perhaps you can call it after you call sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction(). So you will always have a transaction active, but the session may not always be dirty.